# input rounded/replaced to next multiple on keyup

Tags: javascript, rounding, ceil

I have two inputs in first when I type number between 0 - 1.53 I want to automatically replace it to 1.53, when I type 1.54 I want to replace it to 3.06 because (1.53 + 1.53) = 3.06 etc. I use Math.ceil() but I don't know how put this value to input?

Little more explanation:

```
<p>if first input range between 0 - 1.53 result first input = 1.53, second input = 1</p>
<p>if first input range between 1.54 - 3.06 result first input = 3.06, second input = 2</p>
<p>if first input range between 3.06 - 4.59 result first input = 4.59, second input = 3</p>
    <div class="input-box col-sm-12">
        <label>in this input result supposed to round up to next multiple like 1.53 and 3.06 and 4.59...</label><br/>
        <input type="text" value="" id="product_val" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="input-box col-sm-12">
        <label>second input</label><br/>
        <input type="number" value="" id="products_packs" autocomplete="off" disabled>
    </div>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var packSize = 1.53,
    packPrice = 35;
$('#product_val').keyup(function() {
    var area2 = $(this).val().replace(',', '.');
        var area = (Math.ceil(area2 / packSize) * packSize);
    var packs = Math.ceil(area / packSize);
    setPrice(packs * packPrice); 
    setPacks(Math.ceil(area / packSize)); 
});
$('#products_packs').keyup(function() {
    var packs = $(this).val();
    setPrice(packPrice * packs); 
    setArea(packSize * packs); 
    setPacks(packs);
});
function setArea(value) {
    $("#product_val").val(value);
}
function setPacks(value) {
    $("#products_packs").val(value);
    $("#quantity_wanted").val(value);
}
function setPrice(value) {
    $("#products_price").text($("#products_price").text().replace(/[0-9\.\,]+/, parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)));
}
});
```

This line do all job but I need replace value I put in first input by results of this line after stop typing `var area = (Math.ceil(area2 / packSize) * packSize);` how I can do that?

Here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wzte04rj/1/

Comment: selling weed on the website? *#joking*.  I couldn't find what do you need, the fiddle is working fine, where's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for my english... When you write in first input for example 1.2 this supposed to change to 1.53 in moment when you stop typing in this input. So I need to change up value in input to nearest multiple 1.53. This is only for visual effect

Comment: that's fine. so, are you trying to achieve this: change value to 1.53 if it's less than 1.53 and change it to 3.06 if it's between 1.53 and 3.06 and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzte04rj/6/), it will work as you expect.

explanation:

the thing is, you need to do a little math to the job for you. I've come up with this one:

```
( Math.floor( inputValue / packSize ) + 1 ) * packSize;
```

but since it's a simple algorithm, there are many other options as well. the only thing to point is, above line will prodocue **3.06** given **1.53** as input; thus we need to cancel calculations ( write a `return` expression ) before `if` statement if value was already diviceable by `packSize`. like:

```
var divider = inputValue / packSize;

if ( divider == ~~divder )
    return;

( Math.floor( inputValue / packSize ) + 1 ) * packSize;
```

other point is, we're updating the value when user leaves the input. it's not a good experience for user to change input's value as he's typing. but you can change this *event* to whatever you want.

have fun <3

Comment: Thanks, I have on more issue. Is there any posibility to add to this line `$( this ).val( ( Math.floor( val / packSize ) + 1 ) * packSize );` something like `.toFixed(2)` or any other method rounded to 2 decimal?

Comment: @AgnesTom I couldn't find what's the problem. why do u need to add `.toFixed()`?

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wzte04rj/8/ and put in first input 3, result supposed be 3.6 but it is not,  thats why I need to round result to two digit

Comment: @AgnesTom well, [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzte04rj/6/) doesn't have this problem. what have you changed?

Comment: I just change value in `var packSize = 1.53` to `var packSize = 1.2` thats all

Comment: @AgnesTom Yeah, you're right. [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/wzte04rj/9/). `.toFixed` added.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for [this version of question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53873653/1):

I change `area, packs` and `setPacks` in `$('#product_val').keyup` - here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/ybc78kj4/9/):

```
$('#product_val').keyup(function() {
    var area2 = $(this).val().replace(',', '.');
    var area = Math.ceil(area2 / packSize);
    var packs = Math.ceil(area );
    setPrice(packs * packPrice); 
    setPacks(packSize * area); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply but maybe my english is that bad and I write something wrong. All I want is round in first input, so taht what I wrote in this first input supposed to be rounded and displayed also in first input.  In PL: Ponieważ masz polskie nazwisko :) to napisze że chodzi mi o zaokrąglanie tego co wpisze w pierwszym inpucie i wynik zaokrąglania też ma być w pierwszym inpucie

Comment: if you change `setPacks(packSize * area)` to `setPacks(area);` you will get needed round - ale wstawianie go do inputa rozkmiń już sama

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your answer, that's why I edit question post to make situation clearer :)

Comment: guys, what are you talking about?